# Ошибка "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

У меня есть солюшн с несколькими веб приложениями (asp.net mvc4) и библиотеками класов. Проблема в том, что некоторые веб приложения(не все) не запускают ISS при втором и последующих запусках. При первом запуске всё работает, но при последующих я получаю ошибку **This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect**. . Я менял номер порта, но при втором запуске на новом порте снова получаю ошибку. Так же я удалял конфиг из папки .vs, что тоже не помогло

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, Вы не завершаете предыдущий процесс, запуская новый. Необходимо найти его ID и завершить, тогда новый будет доступен для запуска.

Возможно, процесс не будет отображаться в диспетчере задач. Тогда предлагаю использовать [TaskKill](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/taskkill.html) из cmd.

Comment: Нет, сервер не работает, проверил

Comment: @Денис Каким образом проверяли?